# How to merge case insensitive columns with same name in pyspark Dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

What is the way to concatenate two columns which have same column name but case insensitive in a pyspark Dataframe.

```
Example: 

If i have a dataframe like below where Apple and apple are two different columns

+---------------+
|  Apple apple  |
+---------------+
| red   white   |
| blue   yellow |
| pink   blue   |
+---------------+
```

merge it with a delimiter and values alpha sorted

```
+---------------+
|    Apple      |
+---------------+
| red,white     |
| blue,yellow   |
| pink,blue     |
+---------------+
```

Comment: Can you add a code example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 k = 0
 for i in range(len(columns)):
   for j in range(i + 1, len(columns)):
     if columns[i].lower() == columns[j].lower():
         k = k+1
         df = (df.withColumn(columns[i].upper()+str(k),concat(col(columns[i]),lit(","), col(columns[j]))))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a new column with withColumn("newColumnName", )

The udf function should be something that receives 2 Strings, and concat them.

In scala would be something like:

val concat = udf{ (str1:String, str2:String) => str1+str2 }

And then you would call it:

df.withColumn("newColumnName", concat(col("APPLE"), col("apple") )

Remember to:
 1. Import sql spark functions package for col and udf to work.
 2. Set sqlContext.sql("set spark.sql.caseSensitive=true"), so it doesn't take APPLE == apple.
 3. You could drop columns APPLE and apple. So you only have one (the new column)